# Is there any SMPS controllers with CPU core inside?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, cpu

I heard that there is an SMPS controllers combined with CPU core. Or (which is the same in another words) a CPU controller with a wide peripheral to control an SMPS.

Tried to search in Google like "programmable SMPS controller", "SMPS controller with CPU core" and some others but didn't find anything combined in one chip: all I found was a special purpose PWM controllers without any programmable core or a general purpose controllers.

I think that Microchip has something like that.

Can you give me a clue which direction to look?

Comment: Look into [Digitally Enhanced Power Analog (DEPA)](http://www.microchip.com/promo/digitally-enhanced-power-analog) controllers which Microchip makes.

Answer (score 3):

The term you're looking for is "Digital SMPS" or "Digital DC-DC", try to google variations of that.

An example:

http://www.ti.com/download/trng/docs/seminar/Topic_7_Hagen.pdf

Comment: PMBus is also a good search term.

Answer (score 2):

One commercial-grade example that comes to mind is [AXP209](http://linux-sunxi.org/AXP209). Though the IC doesn't include the CPU, instead, it provides interfaces for an external CPU to alter the PMU settings.

Amateur implementations of "Smart SMPS" I have seen are often based on a small MCU like ATTiny which features a fast PWM pin ([example](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-microcontroller-based-boost-converter/)).

Answer (score 2):

Many power supplies using digital control have at their heart a DSC, or "digital signal controller" which essentially is a term for a microcontroller with some DSP enhancements. Examples include Microchip's dsPIC and TI's TMS320/C2000 parts.

These parts don't have a power supply controller on board *per se*, but have sufficient computation power to allow one to control a power supply through software - using difference equations to compute the control law and drive the power devices in a discrete-time way.

The controller is often also used for power management and external communication functions - it is advantageous to be able to use a single part for both control and power management, for cost and system complexity reasons.

Bear in mind that even though these are relatively complex devices, we're still talking about 16-bit parts operating at 50-100 MIPS - a small fraction of the computing power of a full PC, for example, but enough to do what needs to be done in the context of the power supply.